# Parse multiple values of IP addresses in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a script which reads through IPSec .conf files and looks for the string "conn", saves the name of the connection, and then takes an IP address from a line containing "rightsource". Currently there is a one-to-one relationship between the two - if there is one line saying "conn example1" there will be just one line saying rightsource with a single IP address. The part of the script which currently deals with this case is:

```
for CONF in *.conf; do
  set +e
  declare -a CONNS=($(awk '/^conn/ {print $2}' < $CONF | fgrep -vi common))
  declare -a RSOURCES=($(awk -F\= '/(^ *rightsource|^ *# *effectiverightsource)/ {print $2}' < $CONF))

  CONN_SIZE=${#CONNS[@]}
  SOURCE_SIZE=${#RSOURCES[@]}
  if [ $CONN_SIZE != $SOURCE_SIZE ]; then
    #echo "Problem: number of connections $CONN_SIZE not equal to number of source IPs $SOURCE_SIZE in $CONF."
    #echo "Connections=${CONNS[@]}"
    #echo "Source IPs=${RSOURCES[@]}"
    continue
  fi
```

My problem is that I would like to switch our IPSec conf files to a better syntax. Rather than a one to one relationship between conn and rightsource like this:

```
 conn example79
        rightsourceip=44.45.46.79
 conn example80
        rightsourceip=44.45.46.80
```

I would like to use a more efficient syntax:

```
conn example
        rightsubnets={44.45.46.79/32,44.45.46.80/32}
```

The "rightsubnets" curly braces could contain 1, 2 or more IP addresses, which is what I need to pass to the rest of the script so that it can try to ping each one to make sure it's still available.

I can just about understand what the awk command in my existing script is doing, but I have no idea how best to also look for the variable amounts of IP addresses which might be found in the newer syntax. Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: In terms of how you're reading arrays, btw -- see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). Also some issues with missing quotes, and using all-caps variable names means you're risking collisions (POSIX specifies that names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for applications and won't change system or shell behavior when redefined; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Comment: (also, putting the `declare -a` on the same line as the assignment means your command has the exit status of `declare`, not that of the command substitution that gathered the data; and your `[ $foo != $bar ]` should be `[ "$foo" != "$bar" ]` to gracefully handle data with spaces. Okay, done with the kibitzing, on towards the question at hand...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation in native bash (with a fair bit of length spent on debugging facilities) might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in [123].*) echo "ERROR: Requires bash 4.0 or newer" >&2; exit 1;; esac
PS4=':$LINENO+' # if trace logging is enabled, include line numbers

conn_re='^[[:space:]]*conn[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]].*)$'
rightsource_re='^[[:space:]]*(effective)?right(source|subnet)s?=(.*)$'
multimatch_re='^[{](.*,.*)[}]$'

# read document from stdin, and populate an associative array     
declare -A subnets=( )

for conf in *.conf; do : conf="$conf"
  conn=''
  while IFS= read -r line; do : line="$line"
    [[ $line =~ $conn_re ]] && { conn=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; continue; }
    [[ $line =~ $rightsource_re ]] && { subnets[$conn]=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}; }
  done <"$conf"
done
[[ $- = *x* ]] && declare -p subnets >&2 # if tracing enabled, log our extracted values.

handle_result() {
  local conn=$1 element=$2
  element=${element%/32}
  echo "For conn $conn, need to handle element $element"
}

# iterate over the associative array, and call the handler for each address
for conn in "${!subnets[@]}"; do : conn="$conn"
  rightsource=${subnets[$conn]}
  if [[ $rightsource =~ $multimatch_re ]]; then
    IFS=, read -r -a elements <<<"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    for element in "${elements[@]}"; do
      handle_result "$conn" "$element"
    done
  else
    handle_result "$conn" "$rightsource"
  fi
done
```

If given the input:

```
conn example
        rightsubnets={44.45.46.79/32,44.45.46.80/32}
conn next_example
        rightsubnets=1.2.3.4
conn third_example
        rightsubnets={5.6.7.8,9.10.11.12/32}
```

...this emits the output:

```
For conn example, need to handle element 44.45.46.79
For conn example, need to handle element 44.45.46.80
For conn third_example, need to handle element 5.6.7.8
For conn third_example, need to handle element 9.10.11.12
For conn next_example, need to handle element 1.2.3.4
```

...but of course you can change the `handle_result` functionality to do whatever pings or other tests you need.

---

You can see the above code running at https://ideone.com/QrE1Ff

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will be great! I just need to figure out how to integrate it into my existing script...

Comment: If it helps, I edited it to loop over config files, vs expecting input on stdin. Obviously, this means things are a little different from the ideone version (which still looks for a concatenation of all your *.conf files on stdin).

Comment: Looping through the .conf files is perfect, since that's the way we have them laid out. The code works great, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add `rightsubnets` to your `RSOURCES` line, and then deal with the 1-or-more-on-a-line later in your script.  That is, if that particular RSOURCE has the braces, then deal with it as one or more subnets, otherwise as it is today. It's a minimal change that extends the existing code out to handle your new (additional) requirement.

My other suggestion is that you may be extending past the comfortable limits of shell and maybe you should consider python or perl or similar where you can build a better state machine and deal with each line more robustly. For example, if someone has forgotten to put in a `rightsourceip` in a given connection, but put it with another entry (so that it has two), that is probably an error, but you won't be able to easily tell with shell. (That IPSec may catch such a problem may or may not suffice - my experience says that scripts like yours get run often before restarting the tools that depend on those conf files, so the extra error detection is helpful.) That's not the only problem that can crop up that would be easier to catch in a more robust language, there are many others, of course.  It can also be faster since it would only be going through each file once whereas your shell script is reading each file at least twice in its entirety.

Comment: I disagree that one can't easily tell with shell -- see my answer, which tracks a map of conn/subnet associations. (Granted, this is fairly near the limits of bash's data structure support -- you can't *nest* maps, for example, without ugliness such as performing eval-safe escaping and encoding/decoding data, or using namerefs to refer to values stored under distinct identifiers -- but it suffices for the case).

Comment: ...similarly, rereading the input file was an artifact of the original implementation, not a necessity.